# Cake bake undefined function mysql_query on easyphp

Tags: cakephp, mysql, easyphp

when i try to use the shell to build models

> cake bake
>
> M

i get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\Program Files\EasyPH

P-5.3.2\www\cake\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 588

on

phpinfo();

mysql extension is enabled, i'm using mysql driver

running

if(!function_exists('mysql_query')) echo 'error'; else echo 'all fine';

on a separate file prints all fine but on

dbo_mysql.php just before line 588

prints error

i believe the database configuration is correct as on http://127.0.0.1/cake/

it says

Your database configuration file is present.

and

Cake is able to connect to the database.

i'm using the latest stable version of cakephp and easyphp on windows xp pro sp3, paths are setted correctly

any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

creating a "php.ini" file next to php.exe with the following content solved my problem.

EasyPHP-x.x.x\php\php.ini

```
[PHP]

extension_dir = "ext"
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it was easy, easyphp uses a different php.ini than the defoult
creating one solved the problem